# System.Data.DataRow[] Output from AMPscript variable

Tags: ampscript

My "uniqueID" variable is outputting System.Data.DataRow[]. I'm trying to display the value on the page upon success.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-12">
        %%[
            if RequestParameter("submitted") == "submitted" then

                var @email, @fullName, @accountNumber,
               @checkAccountNumber, @numRows, @checkDE, @deNumRows, @createDeRecord,
                @success, @fail, @uniqueID

                set @fullName = RequestParameter('fullName')

                set @email = RequestParameter('email')

                set @accountNumber = RequestParameter('accountNumber')

                set @checkAccountNumber = LookupRows('Unique_ID', 'AccountNumber', @accountNumber)

                set @numRows = RowCount(LookupRows('Unique_ID','AccountNumber',@accountNumber))

                set @checkDE = LookupRows('Unique_ID_Form_Submissions', 'EmailAddress', @email)

                set @uniqueID = LookupRows('Unique_ID', 'UniqueID', @accountNumber)

                set @deNumRows =  RowCount(LookupRows('Unique_ID_Form_Submissions', 'EmailAddress', @email))
                if @numRows > 0 then
                    set @success = 'I found your Unique ID'

                 elseif @numRows == 0 then

                     set @fail = 'I did not find your Account#'

                elseif @deNumRows > 0 then

                    set @duplicatedFound = 'You have already submitted your information.'

                endif
            endif
        endif
    endif
    ]%%

        <p id="success" style="color: green; font-family: arial, san-serif; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">%%=v(@success)=%% %%=v(@uniqueID)=%%</p>  
        <p id="fail" style="color: red; font-family: arial, san-serif; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">%%=v(@fail)=%%</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've taken the liberty of re-formatting your markup/ampscript to give people a better chance at understanding your issue. Blockquotes (lines starting with `>`) generally isn't the right formatting tool to use when code is involved. Instead, I've used a code block, and tried to make your indentation consistent. Formatting as a code block means putting at least 4 blank spaces at the start of each line. The easy way to do that is to highlight your code/markup and press the `{}` button (or `ctrl` + `k` / `cmd` + `k`)

Comment: Thanks Derek. I feel like I'm close on this one. The AMPscript is successfully finding the right Account#, now I just need to display the Unique that is in the same row as the specific Account #.

Comment: Should I be doing a Lookup and not a LookupRows to find my Unique ID based off of the Account# in the same row?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I needed to use a straight Lookup not a LookupRow

set @uniqueID = Lookup('myQ_My_Dealer_Unique_ID', 'UniqueID', 'AccountNumber',@accountNumber)